# Implement Message System into cakephp 2.x

Tags: join, message, foreign-key-relationship, cakephp-2.1

I am  trying to implement a Message System (user to user) into my `cakephp` framework.
Therefore i created the following tables:

### Messages

1. id
2. title
3. body
4. sender_id
5. created
6. response_on

### Messages_Users

1. id
2. message_id
3. recipient_id

The Messages_Users table is used to store the recipient of each sent message.
Then created the corresponding models like this and set up the relationships between the Models.

### Model for Message

```
<?php class Message extends Model{
public $hasMany = array(
        'MessageUser'=>array(
                'className'=>'MessagesUser',
                'foreign Key'=>'message_id')
        );
public $belongsTo = array (
        'User' =>array(
                'className'=>'User',
                'foreignKey'=>'sender_id')
        );
public $hasAndBelongsTo = array(
        'Message'=>array(
                'className'=>'Message',
                'foreignKey'=>'response_on')
        );
```

}

### Model for MessageUser

```
 <?php
     class MessageUser extends Model{
    public $belongsTo = array (
        'User'=>array(
            'className'=>'User',
            'foreignKey'=>'user_id'),
        array(
        'Message'=>array(
            'className'=>'Message',
            'foreignKey'=>'message_id')
                )
        );
```

### Model for User

```
class User extends AppModel{
public $hasAndBelongsTo = array(
        'Message'=>array(
                'joinTable' =>'messages_users',
                'className' =>'Message',
                'foreignKey' =>'recipient_id',
                'associationForeignKey' =>'message_id')
        );
```

Now i want to implement into my MessagesController a function inbox() which shows all messages stored in the database, whom are sent to the corresponding user.
So my approach was putting the function into the MessagesController

```
public function inbox(){
    $uid = $this->Auth->user('id');
    $messages = $this->Message->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                    'recipient_id' => $uid)
            )
            );
```

The function above should perform a join on the table messages and messages_users via the message_id and select the sets of data where the user_id of table messages_users is equal to the recipient_id.

But all I get is an error saying that the column `recipient_id` was not found in the where clause.

How do I instruct the find method to join these tables properly?
I thought it would be enough to link the models, so the cake magic would take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick answer is that your associations are wrong. The long one follows:

First of all there is no association called `hasAndBelongsTo`. The association name is `hasAndBelongsToMany`. Furthermore the associations you've put together in the `Message Model` are a totally wrong or if I may put it this way - you may have not understood them correctly. So the quick fix would be to remove the `hasMany` to `MessageUser`, the `belongsTo` `User` and the wrong `hasAndBelongsTo` `Message` and add a `hasAndBelongsToMany` association to User.

If you want to have `Message hasAndBelongsToMany User` just use that. How [is described here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm). Also HABTM has be discussed many times here so I'm not going to go into detail about it.

However I would like to point you to another possible set up. Now I am proposing this because I saw you tried to also use `hasMany` so there is the possibility to use the so-called `hasManyThrough the Join Model`, but usually that is to be used when you want to store additional data in the join model (MessageUser in your case). Check [this question out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224596/self-habtm-or-hasmany-through-concept-confusion).

Comment: Ive just read the link you provided to HABTM association and i feel enlighted now! i really appreciate this- thank you!

My approach now is to set the association: Message HABTM User. I reedited the database messages_users to the way which is provided in the cakephp link.

Now im thinkin about the association User to Message. In my mind im thinkin of User hasMany Messages - so i am going to implement this into the User Model next.

Kind regards